# Cannot boot from CD Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, system-installation

Initially, I had Windows 8 in my Computer and I accidentally formatted my hard drive. I was not having Windows Installation Disk, and hence I installed Ubuntu 14.04. Now I have the Windows Installation Disk, but I couldn't boot from the CD/DVD (Official). When I start the computer with the CD in the tray, it directly boots to Ubuntu. I have no idea how to boot from Disk. I also have the Ubuntu Live CD, but I couldn't boot that too. All I want is Windows back.

Also, I would like to ask that would formatting hard drive would remove UEFI? (I'm a bit noob regarding booting!). If yes, how would I get it back?

Also, how do we format the whole hard drive without booting from any Disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your BIOS settings (when your computer starts up and shows a key to go to your BIOS settings) go to the boot order (or anything like that) and put CD/DVD Drive on top.

I don't think so that when you format your hard drive your UEFI will be gone. I guess it stays inside your computer not your hard disk. I'm sorry if its gone. Please make sure you look on internet to make sure your UEFI disappears.

For formatting your hard drive with out booting, use an external hard drive case, if you don't have one, boot from your live ubuntu cd (when you boot, click try ubuntu, it won't install on your hard drive) use gparted (application) and format/delete your partitions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't go into the BIOS settings. It never showed any key to press while booting. Additionally, I tried the following keys as well: Del, F1, F2, F10, F11 and F12 keys.

Comment: Take a look at the manual of your Mainboard.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Actually when I installed Ubuntu, the timeout for pressing the F10 key (I'm using HP Desktop) was reduced. I know that's not supposed to happen, but that's EXACTLY what happened in my case. I followed Lemmeask's steps to do it. Thanks again. :)